# Angular expressions not getting evaluated by browser

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to compile a filters page in angular.js . There are four files in my mainly app.js , controllers.js (controllers js file containing controllers and scope), Filters.html(html file for filters) , directives.js(customised directives js file) , and angular.js(using basic angular js library) with the respective functionality . While page loading , I am getting angular expressions with brackets i.e data is not fetched in the scope from controllers and it shows {{..}} in the web page . Can someone suggest whats wrong .. Have posted my code of all files below :

**Filters.html :**

```
<html ng-app="app">

    <head>
        <title>Angular Filters</title>
        <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="lib/Angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <style>
            .css-table-cell
            {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="registerReportCtrl">

        <section  ng-class="{fontSize: fs, redClass:true}">
            <header>
                <header-Line title="heading"></header-Line>
            </header>
        </section>

        <h2 class="center"> {{"Report on :" + title}}  </h2>

        <section class="center" style='width:50%'>
            <label>Sort By:</label>
            <select ng-model="sortBy">
                <option value="levelOfTraining">LevelOfTraining-increasing order</option>
                <option value="costOfTraining">CostOfTraining-increasing order</option>
                <option value="-levelOfTraining">LevelOfTraining-decreasing order</option>
                <option value="-costOfTraining">CostOfTraining-decreasing order</option>

            </select><br><br>

            <label>Filter By:</label>
            <input type="text"  ng-model="filterBy"/>
        </section> <br><br>
        <section class="css-section" >
            <form class="css-form">

                <section class="css-table" >

                    <!-- headers -->
                    <section class="css-table-row" >

                        <section class="css-table-cell">
                            <label class="css-tableheader">Sl No.</label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="css-table-cell">
                            <label class="css-tableheader">Username</label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="css-table-cell">
                            <label class="css-tableheader">Course Selected</label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="css-table-cell">
                            <label class="css-tableheader">Level Of Training</label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="css-table-cell">
                            <label class="css-tableheader">Date Of Registration</label>
                        </section>
                        <section class="css-table-cell">
                            <label class="css-tableheader">Cost Of Training</label>
                        </section>

                    </section>


                    <section class="css-table-row" ng-repeat="request in requests| orderBy: sortBy | filter:filterBy"> 

                        <section class="css-table-cell">
                            <label>{{$index + 1}}</label>
                        </section>             
                        <section class="css-table-cell">
                            <label>{{request.username}}</label>   
                        </section>
                        <section class="css-table-cell">                                
                            <label>{{request.courseSelected| uppercase | limitTo :"3"}}</label>    
                        </section>
                        <section class="css-table-cell">
                            <label>{{request.levelOfTraining| lowercase}}</label>     
                        </section>      
                        <section class="css-table-cell">
                            <label>{{request.dateOfRegistration| date: 'shortDate'}}</label> 
                        </section>
                        <section class="css-table-cell">                             
                            <label>{{request.costOfTraining| currency: "Rs." }}</label>
                        </section>  
                    </section>


                </section>

            </form>
        </section>
        <br>
        <section class="center">Total number of requests:{{requests.length|number:2}}</section>

    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("app" ,["controllers",'directives']);
```

**Directives.js**

```
var directives = angular.module("directives", []);

//directive as element

directives.directive('headerLine', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            'head': '=title'

        },
        template: '<h2> {{ head }}</h2>'
    }
});

//directive as attribute

directives.directive('footerLine', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            'footer': '=title'

        },
        template: '<h2> {{ footer }}</h2>'
    }
});

//directive as class

directives.directive('classDirective', function () {
    return  {
        restrict: "C",
        link: function ($scope, element) {
            element.bind("mouseenter", function () {
                element.css("border-radius", "10px");
                element.css("background-color", "orange");
            });
        }
    };
});

//directive as comment

directives.directive('commentDirective', function () {
    return  {
        restrict: "M",
        link: function () {
            console.log("Using directive as comment.");
        }
    };
});
```

**Controllers.js**

```
controllers.controller('registerReportCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){

$scope.heading="Example for Filters";
$scope.title="Course Registrations";
$scope.requests=[
                 {  
                     username:'Jack',
                     courseSelected:'AngularJS',
                     levelOfTraining:'Basic',
                     dateOfRegistration: new Date(),
                     costOfTraining: 18000                       
                 },
                 {
                     username:'Tom',
                     courseSelected:'AngularJS',
                     levelOfTraining:'Intermediate',
                     dateOfRegistration: new Date(),
                     costOfTraining: 25000                       
                 },
                 {
                     username:'Alice',
                     courseSelected:'AngularJS',
                     levelOfTraining:'Advanced',
                     dateOfRegistration: new Date(),
                     costOfTraining: 35000                       
                 },
                 {
                     username:'Vinu',
                     courseSelected:'BackboneJS',
                     levelOfTraining:'Basic',
                     dateOfRegistration: new Date(),
                     costOfTraining: 15000                       
                 },
                 {
                     username:'Niel',
                     courseSelected:'BackboneJS',
                     levelOfTraining:'Intermediate',
                     dateOfRegistration: new Date(),
                     costOfTraining: 23000                       
                 },
                 {
                     username:'Jasmine',
                     courseSelected:'HTML',
                     levelOfTraining:'Basic',
                     dateOfRegistration: new Date(),
                     costOfTraining: 3000                        
                 },
                 {
                     username:'Daniel',
                     courseSelected:'CSS3',
                     dateOfRegistration: new Date(),
                     levelOfTraining:'Advanced',
                     costOfTraining: 10000                       
                 }
                 ];

 }]);
```

Comment: if it fails to render the content, then it likely that you have an error somewhere. Does the console show any errors? Additionally do you even run your code on a server (local one)?

Comment: any error in the console? Seems like you missed to declare `var controllers = angular.module('controllers', [])` module before using it.

Comment: Yes , thats correct ! gotta define controllers ..thanks it works . Doesnt show any error in editor console though

Comment: Great, glad to hear it helped :) do you want me to add an answer?

Comment: Sure , would be great !

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a working plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/j4vbXvRFIEfGZNpqA7Uv?p=preview). Since you haven't shared the console log so I guess you can find your issue there

and I fixed `controllers.controller('registerReportCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){`.

Check and let me as I havent changed any code

Comment: It should work without IIFE as well (It is not compulsory thing, its good to have), I didn't get you. It does work without IIFE as well

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-bind instead of  angular expression {{ }} .

Comment: Are you kidding? Both does the smae thing.